# Program does not save a csv excel file

Tags: python, csv

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import csv

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(background="lightgrey")
```

#Variables Initiated

```
name = ""
Doctor_Referred = ""
Test_Type = ""
PatientID = 0
Cost = 0
ReportingFees = 0
Balance = Cost - ReportingFees
```

#This will run on button click

```
def on_click():
    with open( "C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Work.csv" , 'a' )as f:
        w = csv.writer(csvfile= f)
        w.writerow([entryPatientID, entryname, entryDoctor_Referred])
    f.close()
```

#labels

```
LabelHeading = Label(root, text = "Patient Details", font = ('Arial',24)).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 20, pady = 10 )
```

#Row1

```
lblname = Label(root, text = "Name", font = ('Arial',14)).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entryname = Entry(root, textvariable = name).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
```

#Row2

```
lblPatientID = Label(root, text = "Patient ID", font = ('Arial',14)).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
entryPatientID =  Entry(root, textvariable = PatientID).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
```

#Row3

```
lblDoctor_Referred = Label(root, text = "Doctor Referred By", font = ('Arial',14)).grid(row = 3, column = 1)
entryDoctor_Referred = Entry(root, textvariable = Doctor_Referred).grid(row = 3, column = 2)

write_Button = Button(root, text = "Save", command=on_click).grid(row = 5, column = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

Please help as the code works but it does not save it in excel file.

Comment: I suggest adding some print statements to various points so you can see what is happening better

Comment: I completed the program using get() statements.

Comment: Please share the solution here so that others may benefit from it. Also, if you identified the problem with the code above, share that as well.Thanks.